# Need all the pictures of same size in gridview android

Tags: android, image, gridview

I want to show all the pictures posted by user's in a gridview in one of my Activities. These are my codes and I am having the result in the picture below. I specified the width and height of each of the pictures in gridview(90dp,90dp), but it doesn't follow.They are being populated as their uploaded size (landscape/portrait). Also even after setting the height of the gridview to wrap_content, the height stays like the picture(about 200dp may b). How do I solve this? Where did I do wrong ?

Model of each picture:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/post2"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

My Gridview in another activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_competition_user"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.golstars.www.glostars.competitionUser"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_competition_user">

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/competitionusergrid"
            />



</ScrollView>
```

My Adapter :

```
MyUser mUser = MyUser.getmUser();
        mUser.setContext(this);
        Picasso.with(this).load(mUser.getProfilePicURL()).into(profileFAB);

        targetList = new ArrayList<>();

        targetAdapter = new GridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), targetList);

        competitionusergrid.setAdapter(targetAdapter);

        String target = "";
        target = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("LOAD_TARGET");
        System.out.println(target);

        if(target.equals("COMPETITION")){
            //if we have competition pics
            if(targetList.isEmpty()){
                ArrayList<String> aux = this.getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("COMPETITION_PICS");
                System.out.println("target list - " + aux);
                for(int i = 0; i < aux.size(); i++){
                    targetList.add(aux.get(i));
                    targetAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


            }
```

How it looks : [UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWdm4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [GridView Setup](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/) with all images are same width & height.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RecyclerView` insteadof `GridView`, RecyclerView is same as GridView & easy to implement.

[image]

Comment: can you please share the UI image how it looks ?

Comment: @rahul sorry forgot to add the UI , i just did please check.

Comment: @shakilMahmudShanto you don't need to use the RelativeLayout for you single view "Model of each picture" that is one extra unnecessary view you are using there. Use only ImageView and see if that is causing the problem. As you have image view set to 90dp but your relative layout is match_parent. Let me know if that does not work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use current code, then you may use the following ImageView,

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {
public SquareImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}}
```

And, the layout of each item,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/post2"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```